# Can we make an array containing pairs?

Tags: c++, stl

I am new to stl and i came across a question where it is required to store a lot of pairs having same characteristics (like:- (string,int)) together. Can we store pairs in array and if so how? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Look up `std::tuple` or `std::pair` and `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
struct demo
{
  string str;
  int i;
};

std::array<demo, 5> arr;  //for fixed size array of 5 elements
std::vector<demo> vec;    //for dynamic size arrays
```

Answer (score 0):

You want ...

> to store a lot of pairs having same characteristics

The terminology is a bit wrong. You want to store many pairs of the same [type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type) (not "characteristics").

You could define your own `struct` as [answered by Nipun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47278238/841108), or use

```
std::array<std::pair<std::string,int>, 10> arr;
```

for an array of 10 pairs of strings and ints.

Spend more time on reading a documentation on [standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and standard [utilities](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility). Perhaps you want some other existing thing (e.g. `std::set` with `std::tuple`, maybe with your own [comparator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare)).

Templates can (and often should) be combined since they are compositional. Be also aware of the [rule of five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).